# Java.Net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream when trying to upload file as a byte stream

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I have an image file that I am trying to upload to a database using a http API. every time I try uploading I get the same error:

```
[monodroid] Not wrapping exception of type Java.Net.ProtocolException from method `Read`. This will change in a future release.
unexpected end of stream
```

Here is my code

```
using GT_MI.API;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ShorelogApp.API.Misc
{

    public class SaveSeas : ApiBase<RequestBase, SaveSeas.Response>
    {

        public class Response : ResponseBase
        {
            public string Path { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file">Byte array representing binary encoded file</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<Response> SaveFileAsync(byte[] file)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = null;

            try
            {
                // Construct the HttpClient and Uri, with a timeout of 16 seconds
                var httpClient = new HttpClient()
                {

                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16)
                };

                var uri = new Uri($"{ApiManager.BaseUrl}/seas/save_seas");
                Debug.WriteLine($"URL: {uri.AbsoluteUri}");

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApiManager.Token) == false)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"[Token]: {ApiManager.Token}");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", ApiManager.Token);
                }
                
                // using byte array content type
                ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(file);
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"); //"application/octet-stream"
                content.Headers.ContentLength = file.Length;
                httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
                
                
                httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var httpResponseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine($"Response Data: {httpResponseBody}");

                var resultJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(httpResponseBody, jsonSerializerSettings);

                Debug.WriteLine($"Response Json:\n{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultJson, Formatting.Indented)}");

                return resultJson;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return HandleException(httpResponseMessage, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding a content header with the size of the file, as I read that sometimes this error is caused by the request body being recognised as the wrong size on the backend, but it didn't work
I tried compressing the file before uploading it, as I thought it might just be too big, but that didn't work.
I tried uploading the file as a string through JSON and uploading it as a ByteArrayContent type, but I always get the same error.

Comment: hey @jdweng I attempted that, so I converted the file to a Base64String using that function, and then submitted the request as a StringContent, with the content length in the header set to the length of the string, however it just came up with the same error

Comment: Run your json through an online checker to see if there are errors.  How large is the file you are uploading?  Only reason that you should be getting an unexpected end of string with Base64, is if the content length is wrong or the json is not valid, or the data is large.  The error could mean the connection is closing.  It is possible a virus checker or firewall is closing the connection.   Another reason a connection will close if there are errors.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer and TCP contains CRC check for errors.  Running a PING check with options PING -t -l 65500 IP

Comment: The size of the file is 146kB (the length of the JSON string is 194219), would that be too large?. I ran it through a json checker and it came back as valid. I'm setting the content length manually so it shouldn't be wrong. maybe there might be an issue with a firewall or something? I am running the request through an android simulator, however I get the same error when running it through my iphone as well. Other requests from the app work just fine however.

Comment: Up to 10M is usually fine.  Other queries are working so credentials are good.  It seems like this query is different is some respect.  Only way of finding out is to debug server.  Octet-Stream probably means a MIME attachment.  See following for sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140).  The Content type has to be consistent with the type.  Octet Stream indicates the body is binary.  You have both json and a file attachment.  Which means the body has more than one type and it should be MIME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, by changing the httpContent type to a MultipartFormDataContent it worked, so the request now looks like

```
                MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(file);
                fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                content.Add(fileContent, "file");
                //ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(file);

                httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

This gets past the end of stream error.